# Solve out specific variables from underdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an underdetermined linear system (more variables than equations) as: 
$ \mathbf{Ax = b} $  and I am interested in solving it a far as possible. The caveat here is that I have my priority list in terms of which variables will be solved out (e.g. solve out firstly x2, then x1, and finally x3).

Is there any computational package that will allow me to do that (I assume by assigning some weight in the variables). I searched Lapack but I did not find something interesting for my case.

Comment: What do you mean by Lapack ?

Comment: I was looking for a gauss elimination related routine that would do the pivots given some weights by the user, but I guess that the solution of @Robert Israel will do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume your matrix $A$ has full row rank.
If you want to solve for a certain set $S$ of variables in terms of the others ($T$), write your system as $A_S x_S + A_T x_T = b$ where $A_S$ is the matrix
formed by the columns of $A$ for variables in $S$, and similarly for $A_T$.
Then this can be done if $A_S$ is invertible, the solution being 
$x_S = A_S^{-1} b - A_S^{-1} A_T x_T$.

Any of Maple, Mathematica, Sage, Matlab, ... should let you do this.